# How to override the built-in exception?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch, throw

I'm using array.pop() function on an integer variable and expecting an error. 
Currently, I get "TypeError: x.pop is not a function" message.
I'd like to override this with my own message using "throw"

I have tried using another try-catch inside the first catch block and this gets the job done. But I'd like to override the first `TypeError` exception in the first try block itself.

```
let x = 3
try {
    x.pop();
// I want to override the exception generated due to this line 
// with my own error message using throw
}
catch (e) {
    try {
        throw thisErr("this is my custom error message..")
    }
    catch (er) {
        console.log(er);
    }
}

function thisErr(message) {
    let moreInfo = message
    let name = "My Exception"
    return `${name}: "${moreInfo}"`
}
```

I'm expecting `My Exception: "this is my custom error message.."`

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.error(er)`.

```
let x = 3
try {
    x.pop();
}
catch (e) {

        var er = thisErr("this is my custom error message..");
        // log(black)  My Exception: "this is my custom error message.."
        console.log(er);
        // error(red)  My Exception: "this is my custom error message.."
        console.error(er);
        // error(red) Uncaught My Exception: "this is my custom error message.."
        throw er;

}
function thisErr(message) {
    let moreInfo = message
    let name = "My Exception"
    return `${name}: "${moreInfo}"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Method:**
You can use the Error constructor to create an Error object and use it as a base to define custom exceptions. This method can generally be used when there are not multiple instances where you would need throw custom exceptions.

```
let x = 3;
try {
    x.pop();
} catch (e) {
    throw new Error({ 
        name: "My Exception",
        message: "this is my custom error message..", 
        toString: function() { return `${this.name} : ${this.message}` } 
    });
}
```

**Better Method:**
Make a class CustomError and define your own constructor for this custom class. This method is a better and a more robust one and can be used when your application needs custom exceptions at a lot of places.

```
class CustomError extends Error {
    constructor(name, message, ...params) {
    // Pass remaining arguments (including vendor specific ones) to parent 
    constructor
        super(...params);

        this.name = name;
        this.message = message;

        // Maintains proper stack trace for where our error was thrown (only available on V8)
        if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
            Error.captureStackTrace(this, CustomError);
        }
    }
}

let x = 3;
try {
    x.pop();
} catch(e){
    throw new CustomError('My Exception', 'this is my custom error message..', e);
}
```